# How to display row twice with one different specific column, using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a row that should be duplicated in certain conditions.
Example:

Case 1:

```
a  b  c   d   e
---------------
1  4  25  10  NULL
```

if e is Null, display a, b and c:

`1 4  25`

Case 2:

```
a  b  c   d   e
---------------
1  4  25  10  55
```

if e is not Null, duplicate the row

`1 4 25`     => column  a,b,c

`1 4 10`   => column  a,b,d

Answer (score 3):

Use this query

Using union you can achieve this use case

```
select a,b,c from table
union all
select a,b,d from table where e is not null
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. So others may benefit @zied123456

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to scan the table twice, then you can use `cross join`and some logic:

```
select a, b, 
       (case when n = 1 then c else d end)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
where n = 1 or
      (n = 2 and e is not null);
```

Comment: the where condition should be

where n = 1 or
      (n = 2 and e is not null)